# Error trying to create seahorse init project, anchor init failed

Tags: blockchain, solana, anchor-solana

[image: 1]

I'm trying to create a new project in Solana with seahorse but I have this issue

```
seahorse init project
```

[image: 2]

I tried updating everything but still having the same problem.
I already have anchor installed and I'm using Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run anchor on Windows. Try installing WSL (windows subsystem for linux).

Go to the left corner of visual studio, press on remote connection, and try running the command again. The Solana BPF compiler doesn't work on Windows and Anchor uses that under the hood.